# Elasticsearch with nested objects query

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have an index with a nested mapping.
I want to preform a query that will return the following: give me all the documents where each word in the search term appears in one or more of the nested documents.

Here is the index:

```
properties: {
      column_values_index_as_objects: {
        type: "nested",
        properties: {
          value: {
            ignore_above: 256,
            type: 'keyword',
            fields: {
              word_middle: {
                analyzer: "searchkick_word_middle_index",
                type: "text"
              },
              analyzed: {
                term_vector: "with_positions_offsets",
                type: "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is the latest query I try:

```
nested: {
       path: "column_values_index_as_objects",
       query: {
          bool: {
             must: [
                {
                   match: {
                       "column_values_index_as_objects.value.analyzed": {
                       query: search_term,
                       boost: 10 * boost_factor,
                       operator: "or",
                       analyzer: "searchkick_search"
                      }
                   }
                }
```

For example if I search the words 'food and water', I want that each word will appear in at least on nested document.
The current search returns the document even if only one of the words exists

Thanks for the help!

Update:
As Cristoph suggested, the solution works. now I have the following problem.

Here is my index:

```
  properties: {
      name: {
        type: "text"
      },
      column_values_index_as_objects: {
        type: "nested",
        properties: {
          value: {
            ignore_above: 256,
            type: 'keyword',
            fields: {
              word_middle: {
                analyzer: "searchkick_word_middle_index",
                type: "text"
              },
              analyzed: {
                term_vector: "with_positions_offsets",
                type: "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And the query I want to preform is if I search for 'my name is guy', and will give all the documents where all the words are found - might be in the nested documents and might in the name field.
For example, I could have a document with the value 'guy' in the name field and other words in the nested documents

Comment: If you want **AND** in terms then operator value should be `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: Thanks! if I use 'AND' it means it will give me results only if the WHOLE sentence is in the value.
And this is not what I want.
I want that each word will appear inn at least one sub document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, I usually split the terms and generate a request like this (foo:bar is an other criteria on an other field) :

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "nested": {
          "path": "column_values_index_as_objects",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "column_values_index_as_objects.value.analyzed": {
                "query": "food",
                "boost": "10 * boost_factor",
                "analyzer": "searchkick_search"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "nested": {
          "path": "column_values_index_as_objects",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "column_values_index_as_objects.value.analyzed": {
                "query": "and",
                "boost": "10 * boost_factor",
                "analyzer": "searchkick_search"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "nested": {
          "path": "column_values_index_as_objects",
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "column_values_index_as_objects.value.analyzed": {
                "query": "water",
                "boost": "10 * boost_factor",
                "analyzer": "searchkick_search"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "query": {
          "term": {
            "foo": "bar"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I have another question.
If I want to do this and also add another regular field? not nested, how would that work?
Meaning if I look for 'one two three' - If I have 'one' and 'two' in the nested fields but 'three' in the other field - I want to get this document

Comment: Anyone has a clue...?

Comment: Just add your query into the "must" array. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @Christophe Quintard thanks a lot!
I'm not sure it fully answers my problem, I've updated my question, could you please take a look?
Appreciate your help!

Comment: Any thoughts here?